# Is it possible to embed Piwik widgets without using an iframe?

Tags: php, codeigniter, matomo

After reading this page: http://piwik.org/docs/embed-piwik-report/

I have learned to embed Piwik widgets using an iframe but I want to know is it possible to embed them without an iframe an by using PHP? I am using codeigniter (framework) for my php development.

Comment: I can't find any other way to embed a Piwik widget besides iframe. Probably they don't have support for this yet. You can however embed static image graphs: http://piwik.org/docs/analytics-api/metadata/#toc-static-image-graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can create via Piwik API, to pull it in an build as you choose:
http://piwik.org/docs/analytics-api/reference/

Comment: How about the graphics and the data exporting in different formats?